# Search a whole Git repository

Tags: git, search

I'm looking for a tool that lets me perform a search through a complete Git repository (all branches).  Ideally that tool would take some search pattern and would return a list of commit objects where that pattern appears (either in the file diffs or in the commit message [ I'm more interested in searching for the pattern in the commit messages than in the files]).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For searching commit messages, use `git log --grep <regex> [branches]`.

For searching commit *diffs*, use `git log -G <regex> [branches]`.

To specify all existing local branches, use `--all` in place of the branch name.

If you want only a list of hashes, use `--format=%H`.

Comment: Ha!  Exactly what I needed (and `--all` really gives me all branches, including the remote tracking ones, which is indeed what I need).  Thanks!

Comment: would this apply for the removed objects during squash?

Comment: No, those objects are no longer part of the branch. Try something like `git fsck --lost-found` to find their object IDs if they haven't been GC'd yet.

Answer (score 0):

### `git grep` a whole repository: ie: *all* commits (and branches) in the entire repo

Use `--all` in place of the branch name or commit hash, and do this to search for `"search string"` in all commits and branches:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" --all)"; \
    git grep -n "search string" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

Example from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a commit_array <<< \
    "$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" --all)"; \
    git grep -n "\bhey\b" "${commit_array[@]}"
```

I originally wrote about this here: [Stack Overflow: How to `git grep` through a range of commits, all commits from the current commit back to the parent commit, or through all commits in entire repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931035/4561887). See that answer for a lot more detail and other options and scenarios.